# Plesk VPS: How can I stop Server Health Emails?

Tags: centos, vps, plesk, plesk-onyx

I run a Plesk VPS, where I get around 25+ 'Administrator' emails, hourly, detailing minor changes in Server Health.

Typically, they include variants of:

```
Server: mail.example.com.

Server health parameter "Services > Apache memory usage" changed its status from "red" to "yellow".
```

The "Yellow" to "Red" interchanging in each email.  Is there a way I can stop these emails or at best reduce them to some kind of 'End of Day' Summary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plesk does not provide a GUI for configuring Email Notifications from the Health Monitor, you have to modify an XML file:

**To configure Health Monitor:**

1. Download the current configuration file by clicking the `Download Configuration File` button in `Server Management > Health Monitoring`.
2. Change the configuration file in any text editor. You can define:

   - Alarm threshold for each parameter.
   - Type of the alarm for each parameter: Exceeding of an absolute value, a relative value, or a trend value.
   - Trend calculation parameters.
   - Email notification parameters. The detailed file structure and description for each of the file parameters is provided in the top of the configuration file.
3. Upload the modified file to Plesk by clicking the `Upload Configuration File` button in `Server Management > Health Monitoring`.